In Flutter, if a BoxDecoration has both borderRadius and boxShadow, the border is not displayed
The problem is simple, I have a widget called SelectBox with an "active" parameter. If active is true then there should be both the shadow and the white border, but the border doesn't appear anymore! When active is false the border is shown. I have this problem since I updated flutter (3.27.1). Here is my widget:
class SelectBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectBox({super.key, required this.text, required this.active});
  final bool active;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            if (active)
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white.withValues(alpha: 0.7),
                blurRadius: 30,
                blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer,
              )
          ]),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

If I try to remove the borderRadius from the box decoration the border is displayed but it isn't rounded! I tried different solutions, for example I tried to use two different container, one for the shadow and the other for the border but nothing to do.
I created a issue ticket on the flutter project where you can find more detailed info (such as flutter doctor): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/160716
screenshot
UPDATE: I tried this widget on some emulators and it works properly. Actually, only on my "• Redmi Note 8 Pro (mobile) • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)" doesn't work. I also tried to build and run the app from another computer with the same flutter version and the bug persists!!!

can you share the screenshot

@pskink your code works but if I add blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer it doesn't work anymore! I just tried all the BlurStyle and only when it is .outer then the border is not displayed. There should be some error in the new flutter version for some type of devices. What do you think?

are you familiar with CustomPaint? If so try, just for test, to call Canvas.drawRRect with those 4 blur styles (you have to use Paint.maskFilter set to MaskFilter) and check how it is drawn on your device

@pskink I tried with CustomPaint and it works. Now I don't know if I should use this solution or maybe I should downgrade flutter. I have an update to send in production.

hmmmm, really strange, so you mean that paint.maskFilter = MaskFilter(BlurStyle.outer, 30) really works but BoxShadow( color: Colors.white.withValues(alpha: 0.7), blurRadius: 30, blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer, ) deosnt? did you also use paint.color = Colors.white.withValues(alpha: 0.7)?

@pskink ye! really really weird.
Here is my paint:
`void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
final rect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
const Radius.circular(10),
);
final paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.white.withValues(alpha: 0.7)
  ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, 30);

canvas.drawRRect(rect, paint);

final borderPaint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.white
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 5;

canvas.drawRRect(rect, borderPaint);

}`

@pskink ei, call the toPaint on the boxShadow works fine too!

ok, so i would just for testing, use ShapeDecoration and change the sources here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/main/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/shape_decoration.dart#L421 - try instead of canvas.drawPath(_shadowPaths[index], _shadowPaints[index]); use canvas.drawPath(_shadowPaths[index], myTestingPaint); - remember to restore the sources to the original content  after the testing! btw if all fails you can always create your custom Decoration class (class MyDecoration extends Decoration { ...) and test your code there

@pskink I tried this but nothing happens: canvas.drawPath(               _shadowPaths[index],               BoxShadow(                 color: Colors.red,                 blurRadius: 100,                 blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer,               ).toPaint());
The border doesn't shown but the shadow is not the one that I inserted in the code

@pskink eiiii, the print doesn't show but if I insert the print in the first "if" it does log! link
Then in the flow _decoration.shape.preferPaintInterior is set to true

Ei @pskink, what do you mean with "play with preferPaintInterior"?

i mean use Container(decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(preferPaintInterior: true / false, borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)), border: Border.all(...)

Ei @pskink, It seems that preferPaintInterior is not a parameter of RoundedRectangleBorder Widget

@pskink Yes, I saw it but I think that to change this parameter maybe I need to edit or wrap a Flutter class widget and override the getter. Actually, on the github issue ticket they found the problem! Running the app with --no-enable-impeller it works fine. Impeller seems to be a rendering engine on the new flutter version. I'll wait for a concret solution to the problem

your code is working perfectly in flutter 3.27.0


Weird! On my redmi note 8 pro it doesn't work. Running flutter doctor everything is ok. You can find more information on the github issue ticket that I opened, there is also a screenshot

I just copied your code and run with Flutter 3.27.1. It's working fine for me. There should be some other issue.



Weird! On my redmi note 8 pro it doesn't work. Running flutter doctor everything is ok. You can find more information on the github issue ticket that I opened, there is also a screenshot. I added the link on the post.
